# How to iterate through a directory and sub-directories using a URL

Tags: php, wordpress, iteration, recursiveiterator

I'm trying to iterate through files in a directory and files in sub-directories within:

```
<?php

$dir = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js';

echo $dir;

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST );

foreach ( $iterator as $path ) {
    if ($path->isDir()) {
        print('<div> DIR : ' . $path . PHP_EOL . "</div>");
    } else {
        $path_parts = pathinfo($path);
        $file_parts = $path_parts['extension'];
        if ($file_parts == "js")
        {
            $array = explode("/opt/lampp/htdocs", $path);
            unset($array[0]);
            echo $path = implode("/", $array);
            print("<div>http://localhost$path" . PHP_EOL . "</div>");
            echo("<script src='http://localhost/$path'></script>");
        } else if ($file_parts == "css") {
            echo("<script src='http://localhost/$path'></script>");
            echo("<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://localhost/$path'>");
        }
    }
}

?>
```

I, however, get the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(http://localhost/projects/wordpress_projects/wp-content/themes/rev_cust/js): failed to open dir: not implemented in /opt/lampp/htdocs/projects/wordpress_projects/wp-content/themes/rev_cust/header.php:40
```

**`echo $dir;`** gives:

> http://localhost/projects/wordpress_projects/wp-content/themes/rev_cust/js

**The StackTrace:**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(http://localhost/projects/wordpress_projects/wp-content/themes/rev_cust/js): failed to open dir: not implemented in /opt/lampp/htdocs/projects/wordpress_projects/wp-content/themes/rev_cust/header.php:40 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/projects/wordpress_projects/wp-content/themes/rev_cust/header.php(40): RecursiveDirectoryIterator->__construct('http://localhos...') #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/projects/wordpress_projects/wp-includes/template.php(684): require_once('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/projects/wordpress_projects/wp-includes/template.php(643): load_template('/opt/lampp/htdo...', true) #3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/projects/wordpress_projects/wp-includes/general-template.php(45): locate_template(Array, true) #4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/projects/wordpress_projects/wp-content/themes/rev_cust/index.php(18): get_header() #5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/pro in /opt/lampp/htdocs/projects/wordpress_projects/wp-content/themes/rev_cust/header.php on line 40
```

How can I fix it and make it work right?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: `$dir`  should be a local filesystem path, not url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct` expects a path not a uri. To fix this try:

```
$dir = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/js'; // This gives you a path instead
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an URL, while you have to pass a path.

Check it here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php